# Converting ascii characters in text file to Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, ascii

We are creating a website using Django 1.5, We have several large text files stored on the server that are to render with the web page, depending on the country. The problem is that these text files contain the copyright symbol (c) and we keep getting a 'Non-ascii character' error, and the text does not load. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to successfully convert one to the other?

Selections of the Code:

```
#Open file, where filename is our variable            
with open(filename) as f:
        #Append (It is in a loop, and we are only passing 1 document variable
        document=document + f.read()
        f.close
```

We have tried using:

- mark safe (in django)
- `smart_str`
- `.encode('utf8')`

But to no avail, the page continues so spit back an error saying there is an ascii character that it cannot convert. Any ideas?

Here is the error we keep getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /<website-hidden>/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 950: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You don't have ASCII if you get a decode error. Note that `f.close` does *nothing*, you need to call it explicitly. Not that you need it, since you use `with`, so the file is closed anyway.

Comment: You want to *decode* the data from the encoding used in the file.

Comment: We have tried: document.decode("ascii"), document.decode("utf8") and both those with their respective 'encode' counterparts. Still nothing. Could you be more specific?

Comment: What encoding is using your file?

Comment: You need to figure out what encoding *does* work. The byte `0x92` is not ASCII, nor is it UTF-8. The U+00A9 codepoint (`©`) is `C2A9` in UTF-8 hex.

Comment: `'\x92'.decode('cp1252')` is an RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. There is no encoding for which `'\x92'` is a copyright symbol. But perhaps there are other symbols besides copyright symbols which are non-ascii. So try decoding with `cp1252`.

Comment: @unutbu: Nice find. That's probably it.

Comment: I apologize, the copyright is not the only symbol we are having troubles with, but it is the primary problem. The code posted was different, but none the less, is something we would like to solve.

Comment: @unutbu, putting 'cp1252' in our decode returned the error: _'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 672: character maps to <undefined>_

Comment: Excuse me for being repetitive but I think first thing you need to be 100% positive sure is what encoding uses your file.Hint: copy the text to say... `notepad` :P, then Save as and in the bottom of the windows select UTF-8 then you know you use utf-8 and can decode it from python

Comment: @PauloBu, we have confirmed that the text file is coded in utf-8. We are still encountering the same error.

Comment: @JoeKelley: The error message says you're *encoding* with the `charmap` codec, not *decoding* with `cp1252`. Are you sure this error is occurring on the same line as where you are using `f.read().decode('cp1252')`?

Comment: By the way, the error message mentions `u'\xa9'` which is the copyright symbol. So you have successfully decoded the text file at that point. That's good!

Comment: You might find it useful to read [Pragmatic Unicode -- How do I stop the pain](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html). It will help you reason about when to decode and when to encode, and how to debug these kind of problems.

Comment: It is a great book, good explanations, but I think you may read it if you like the subject or want to get a PhD in it, I'll suggest a better (spolsky) approach: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . That is **lovely**.

Comment: @JonKelley haven't you found the solution yet?

Comment: Restarted the computer and eclipse and it magically worked now. No idea what prompted the error, nor what fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restart of the computer and eclipse seemed to do the trick. Perhaps it was a problem with the cache? Either way, strange error...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the copyright symbol isn't a strict ASCII character, as it's 8th (most significant) bit is 1. ASCII only uses 7 bits. You need to tell python that the file isn't ASCII data, but something like "Extended ASCII", "ISO 8859-1" or "ISO Latin-1" data.

As such, you need to read it as bytes and then convert it to a string using that decoding. You can then re-encode it to anything you want, including UTF-8.

Exact handling for this depends if you are using python 2.x or 3.x.

Ref
http://www.ascii-code.com/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII